# NSURLConnection and Authenticating to webservices behind ssl?

Tags: objective-c, authentication, nsurlconnection

I'm currently trying to connect to a webservice placed on https://xxx.xxx.xx/myapp

It has anonymous access and SSL enabled for testing purposes atm.

While trying to connect from the 3G network, i get Status 403: Access denied. You do not have permission to view this directory or page using the credentials that you supplied.

I get these headers while trying to connect to the webservice locally:

**Headers**

Request URL:https://xxx.xxx.xx/myapp

Request Method:GET

Status Code:200 OK

---

**Request Headers**

GET /myapp/ HTTP/1.1

Host: xxx.xxx.xxx

Connection: keep-alive

Authorization: Basic amViZTAyOlE3ZSVNNHNB

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1) AppleWebKit/535.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17.0.963.56 Safari/535.11

Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch

Accept-Language: sv-SE,sv;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4

Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3

---

**Response Headers**

HTTP/1.1 200 OK

Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.0

X-Powered-By: ASP.NET

Date: Thu, 16 Feb 2012 12:26:13 GMT

Content-Length: 622

---

But when accessing outside the local area, we get the big ol 403. Which in turn wants credentials to grant the user access to the webservice.

However, i've tried using the ASIHTTPRequest library without success, and that project has been abandoned. And they suggest going back to NSURLConnection.

And i have no clue where to start, not even which direction to take.

```
-connection:(connection *)connection didRecieveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
```

The above delegate method of `NSURLConnection` doesnt even trigger. So i have no idea what so ever how to authenticate myself.

All i get is the parsed results of the xml elements of the 403-page.

I needs dem seriouz helps! plx.

Comment: A typo? Try didReceive... (instead of Recieve).

Comment: It's a typo here, not in the actual code.

Comment: Does the remote site use a self-signed cert?

Comment: Any hints in the server's error-logfile?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was all just a major f-up.

The site had ssl required and enabled, and setting ssl required for the virtual directories does some kind of superduper meta-blocking.

So, by disabling ssl required for the virtual directories, it runs over ssl and is not blocking 3G access..